# Android - play sound when device plugged in audio jack

Tags: android, audio, playing, headphones

I want to play audio file while I have a device plugged in audio jack (not necessary just headphones).

If it helps I am only interested in Android version 4.3 and above and I am willing to root the phone if necessary.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Some kind of hack but it is not working.

   ```
    try {
       Class audioSystemClass = Class.forName("android.media.AudioSystem");
       Method setForceUse = audioSystemClass.getMethod("setForceUse", int.class, int.class);
       setForceUse.invoke(null, 1, 1);

       MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bad);
       mp.start();

   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       Log.d("mediaException", "class", e);
   } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
       Log.d("mediaException", "method", e);
   } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
       Log.d("mediaException", "access", e);
   } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
       Log.d("mediaException", "invocation", e);
   }
   ```
2. Found this here in some thread but it is also not working:

   ```
   AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

   audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
   audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

   MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bad);
   mp.start();
   ```
3. Using MediaRouter class I tried to get available routes. But when something is plugged in audio jack only route available is "Headphones".

   ```
   MediaRouter router = (MediaRouter) this.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_ROUTER_SERVICE);

   for (int i = 0; i < router.getRouteCount(); i++) {
       Log.d("playSound", router.getRouteAt(i).toString());
   }
   ```

Comment: How exactly it is not working?

Comment: It's not playing audio on speakerphone while something is plugged in audio jack. That is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Is not that an expected/normal behavior?

Comment: You haven't mentioned which stream type you're using for the playback. That's pretty important.

Comment: @shoerat yes, this is expected behavior. I will try to reformulate the question.

Comment: @Michael I am not sure about what are you talking about?

Comment: The stream type. As in `STREAM_MUSIC`, `STREAM_VOICE_CALL`, etc. For example, the hack you listed at the top would only work for `STREAM_MUSIC` (and maybe `STREAM_SYSTEM`).

Comment: I have tried to add : MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bad);
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); but the hack still doesn't work (device: Nexus 5)

Comment: Try with `STREAM_NOTIFICATION`

Comment: I have tried STREAM_NOTIFICATION and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how this can be done. Notice that MediaPlayer and AudioManger are in the same mode. I tried this on Nexus 5 (4.4.2)

```
        final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

        MediaPlayer mp = null;
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bad);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        mp.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also important to add permission usage to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```